# Composer using the wrong PHP binary

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I am using MacOS Big Sur.

I have a PHP 7.4 project with composer. Yesterday, after some failure with brew (that decided to update PHP when I asked to update git...), I had to reinstall my PHP7.4 (still using brew through brew install php@7.4).

The issue is that right now, there is also a PHP binary preinstalled in MacOS, which is in PHP 7.3.

For some weird reasons, Composer still uses that 7.3 PHP Binary instead of brew's 7.4. I have added 7.4 to my path and made an alias between PHP and the 7.4 binary. Also, I can't remember what I did to completely override the system binary when I first installed my project 6 months ago.

The issue is that since my composer is set in 7.4 and it uses a 7.3, I get many errors.

What can I do ?

EDIT : `/usr/bin/env php` seems to point to the 7.3 one. Maybe an environment issue.

Regards,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, after some digging :

- 7.3 is in /usr/bin, I can't delete it.
- Echoing $PATH show me that /usr/bin has higher priority than my brew folder
- /usr/local/bin has higher priority than /usr/bin, so I've put a symlink inside which overrides the 7.3 completly.

Maybe it's not the best solution but it works.